# MS_Access Report Design View Very Slow

Tags: ms-access

Reports in design view run extremely slow, painfully slow!  I have done compact & repair, split my database, disabled auto-correct, changed printer and I am out of ideas!
Please help!

this is for all reports

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the computer in question has a valid default printer, and one that is NOT a network printer. Because you might not have a real printer attached, then setup a PDF printer. This setup is also great for testing how printing reports will work, and you save a ton of paper.

So, if your default printer is a network printer, or a printer that is off line or does not exist? Access attempts to talk and communicate with that printer to gather information about the printer for layout. If the printer is non exist, then it becomes painfully slow.

You also want to check for ANY linked table that is dead, or does not exist any more (say a stray link to Excel or anything else - this also will cause a terrible slow down).

If your database is split and the back end is say on a shared server folder? Then before ANY design work, simply open any linked table to the back end (any table - does not even have to be the one the report is based on). Open that table, minimize it, and now try design on the report.

The above two tips should eliminate the "slow" flip into design mode.